# Which one should I should for streaming data? Spark streaming with DynamoDB or Cassandra in AWS

Tags: cassandra, amazon-dynamodb-streams

We are working on storing user clicking data coming as streaming data.
I have been investigating about possible ways to do it in AWS.
One way to do it is using DynamoDB to store the data along with all the native tools from AWS.
The other method is to install the spark streaming with Cassandra.
Datastax is providing the integrated package to install them on AWS.
From the reference I found online.
It seems that using  native DynamoDB from AWS could be more expensive.
But it will save time on maintaining the system.
Does anyone have experience in it before and could provide some insights and suggests about the pros and cons of both of them?
Furthermore, We want to create a system that the database could handle both the batch data and streaming such as the lambda architecture. So both the streaming data and batch data will be end up with the same database. As far as I know, Cassandra is good for this case. Does DynamoDB support it as well?
Thank you so much!